# What is the right way to save an array as data in core data?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

As title, I have an array of multiple objects and I wish to store them in core data(I understand that we can't save array into core data so I break my code into json[0][i]["ID"].int format), perhaps you will be clearer after reading my code

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    socket.on("reply") {data, ack in
        let json = JSON(data)
        print("database replied")
        print(json[0].count)

        for var i=0; i<json[0].count; ++i{
            newUser.setValue(json[0][i]["ID"].int, forKey: "patientID")
            newUser.setValue(json[0][i]["Name"].string, forKey: "patientName")
            newUser.setValue(json[0][i]["Mileage"].double, forKey: "patientMileAge")
            do{
                try context.save()
            }catch{
                print("Could not save data")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what my data would look like
[image: data]

Here comes the troubles, i only get [ID:4, Name:'hung', Mileage:'0.23'] as the result, the former 2 arrays have been replaced.

Why can't I save them as I intended?

Comment: Just a side note and perhaps not really relevant since Swift 3.0 will take a while but C-style for-loops will be deprecated so perhaps it's a good idea to start getting used to using `for-in` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line of code into your loop:

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
```

This should work, write me if it didn't

Answer (score 2):

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
```

should be inside the loop, because otherwise you create one object and then repeatedly update it and save the change (so the old value is overwritten)

Answer (score 1):

because you're not adding 3 entries, you're only updating the values for one.

you need to move

```
    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
```

inside your for loop